# Sequelize query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, backend

There are group of parents having children, let’s say P1 ==> [C1,C2], P2 ==> [C3,C2], P3 ==> [C1], and many other combinations, but I want to get only those parents who has only C1 child or who has only [C2,C3].

Comment: Please show model definitions along with their associations

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.